# Mobile Safari does not play sound

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, audio

Simply, a user clicks a button on a web page, the front end makes a call to a restful api and it returns an ArrayBuffer that contains audio data. I then call the following function in order to play the audio through the browser:

```
playSound(arrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer) {
    const context = new AudioContext();
    context.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer, function (data) {
        resolve(data);
        const source = context.createBufferSource();
        source.buffer = data;
        source.connect(context.destination);
        source.start(0);
    });

}
```

The audio plays fine when using my desktop browser, but when I use my iPhone's safari browser the sound never gets played.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: check whether this help https://gist.github.com/kus/3f01d60569eeadefe3a1

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya unfortunately the solution at the link did not work and this is still an issue.